# Electric Analogy to Hydro-Electric Power Plant

Tags: power, water

What is the right [electric analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy) for the system of power generation in [hydro-electric power plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroelectricity)? I am especially curious in designing the surge tank with the symbols for electric components.

[image]

Comment: These "analogies" are just analogies. There isn't an equivalent for everything. It's also a pretty meaningless question – what *property* of this system, which really isn't even a circular system, so it can't be represented as an electric circuit, do you care about?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the dynamics of surge tank. Especially, how the surge tank behaves upon sudden closing of the valve (the one between the surge tank and the turbine). Since I couldn't find any good PC simulations programs, I began to think of simulating the fluid dynamics with electric simulations.

Comment: yeah, but really, when you start digging deeper into fluid dynamics, all the "electric circuits are like water circuits" things break down; things simply don't map to each other. I honestly NEVER understood the better half of these water analogies – and I studied electrical engineering – because all the model assumptions necessary to make the water circuit behave like an electrical circuit are more complex (and not like water in pipes *actually* behaves) than actually understanding electricity. Also, honestly, fluid dynamics is way more complex than simple linear electrical circuits?

Comment: Pipe resistance is non-linear (depends on flow rate), one important reason why it is more complex than electrical circuits.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, IMHO, hydro-electric analogies serve to help you to make the transition into the world of electricity. That's their use or purpose. Once you start getting and seeing how electricity works, you don't need them any more.

Comment: @Marino I really don't agree. The analogies don't really work that well, because basic properties that make it easy to make a mental model of electricity don't exist for water. I mean, your system is the best example: in electricity, since the flow isn't a closed loop, practically no charge would flow. In your picture, the turbine would magically run until the reservoir is empty. Electricity doesn't work like that at all.

Comment: Honestly, we never used water analogies in our electrical engineering courses at uni, ever, not even in the first week, and the folks that didn't have higher-grade physics in school but learned water analogies were *worse* off than those who never heard of the water analogies.

Comment: I think the water analogy is from a time when electricity was largely a new phenomenon, and people had to come up with a "teaser" for engineers who know steam engines. I mean, honestly, the guy that put up Germany's first Electrical Engineering university program would have probably looked at you very sternly and said something like "and now you go back and read the works of Kirchhoff and Maxwell's equations, I didn't spend years proving the existence of electromagnetic waves for you to use such wrong models".

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the hydrolelectic dam is a circular system ... the OP failed to include evaporation and condensation in the diagram

Comment: @jsotola no, he didn't "forget" that, it's not there, and the turbine still runs until the reservoir is empty. and that's why that model is crap ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, that's why the ground is also represented with the reservoir of water. This makes it a [close loop](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/watcir.html). Analogies serve to describe the **similarities** between two things. Look up the definition for ['analogy'](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/analogy).

Comment: @Marino um, that's a bit of a strange argument you're bringing there, seeing that the website specifically illustrates that an electric circuit is similar to an actual water loop, and that the ground "reservoir" thing is just a "pressure reference". No, it does **not** make it a loop. Yes, analogies are used to describe similarities. Like, I can teach you electricity using angry dogs as analogy, which behave like electricity, unless we're considering any very basic fact about electricity or dogs.

Comment: @Marino but I appreciate the thing that you're mentioning here: *Analogies serve to describe the similarities between two things.* I don't see how that tank is similar to anything that exists in electricity. I don't think it's useful to try and find similarity in things that are different.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, do you know any good simulator of fluid dynamics?

Comment: yes, openfoam is what people use scientifically. But really, you'd be simulating something that has nothing to do with electricity.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyN3hJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:

You get oscillations, which is the correct scenario. Look this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbyL--6q7_4), the turbine valve has to move very slowly, additional deflector is used for fast rpm control, not the valve , it would tear off the entire mountain.

Comment: Yes. Inductance is the inertia of the water. If the reservoir level was not infinite (level would drop during simulation), it could be modeled as a large pre-charged capacitor. Pipe resistance is non-linear (depends on flow rate), so if your simulator can't deal with non-linear resistance, it won't be able to solve this. For residential and industrial pipe sizes, the resistance is highly non-linear. For a really large pipe, it might be closer to linear.

Comment: The capacitor starts oscillating with the inductors and the model brakes down. I think the battery model is a much better alternative.

Comment: @Marino That's the way it is, you have to open the valve very slow and close it also very slow, this is also in the reality. Perhaps the inductance and capacitance are not the best value you choose.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, some component should be added to the capacitor in order to prevent oscillations. In reality, sometimes you need to close the valve quick to prevent the disaster. That's why the surge tank is there.

Comment: @Marino Again, quick closing the valve would make a disaster.

Comment: According to your schematics, the surge tank (C1) keeps on filling with water, as if it's located beneath the penstock pipes. In reality (and in normal conditions), the surge tank is filled up to it's minimum as the water is attracted by the gravitational force of planet Earth. Analogously, the C1 is not charged to its maximum value. Therefore, an controlled source of voltage is needed in C1s branch to simulate the gravitational force and counteract the voltage produced by the V1.

There are emergency situations when the turbine valve has to be immediately closed to prevent material damage.

Comment: THAT VIDEO IS TEDIOUS AND DREADFUL AND GOES ON AND ON FOREVER IN AN UNLISTENABLE MONOTONE AND IT REALLY OUGHT TO BE REPLACED BY A VIDEO THAT IS COMPETENT AND THAT USES A HUMAN VOICE ACTOR INSTEAD OF A COMPUTER. IT IS VERY BAD.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKk95Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>